# Net dns zone, query can't find domain

Tags: google-cloud-dns

Yesterday I setup a new dns zone netdav.net. I pointed the nameservers from Dotster where it is registered to Google's cloud name servers. I am unable to query my own DNS name using Googles name server's that I was told to use. They are:

```
ns-cloud-b1.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-b2.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-b3.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-b4.googledomains.com.
```

Below is an example error on nslookup:

```
> server ns-cloud-b1.googledomains.com
Default Server:  ns-cloud-b1.googledomains.com
Addresses:  2001:4860:4802:32::6b
          216.239.32.107

> set q=NS
> netdav.net
Server:  ns-cloud-b1.googledomains.com
Addresses:  2001:4860:4802:32::6b
          216.239.32.107

*** ns-cloud-b1.googledomains.com can't find netdav.net: No response from server
```

I'm having difficulty getting a custom Domain Name setup for an e-mail provider and I suspect something is wrong with Google's DNS servers.

Below are some records in netdav.net:

```
netdav.net. NS  21600   
ns-cloud-b1.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-b2.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-b3.googledomains.com.
ns-cloud-b4.googledomains.com.
    netdav.net. SOA 21600   
ns-cloud-b1.googledomains.com. cloud-dns-hostmaster.google.com. 1 21600 3600 259200 300

@.netdav.net.   MX  300 
10 mail.protonmail.ch.
```

Google's instructions for name server setup:

```
Registrar Setup
This zone will not normally be usable until you register the related domain and configure it to use these name servers:

    Type    Data
    NS  
    ns-cloud-b1.googledomains.com.
    ns-cloud-b2.googledomains.com.
    ns-cloud-b3.googledomains.com.
    ns-cloud-b4.googledomains.com.
```

Comment: Yes, well the problem is that I have MX & TXT records that are not found.

Comment: Additionally, If I use online DNS tools to verify the health, they all report a failure to resolve netdav.net. This is not a good situation to be in. I may just ditch Google's Cloud DNS if it is too problematic. I have a billing account, yet I can't get customer service for a new service that is having issues.

Comment: All of the ns-cloud-??.googledomains.com name servers answer REFUSED for netdav.net. queries—did you delete your zone in the last two weeks? Some folks also had billing issues in mid-June that could have caused problems, especially if you were on the free trial plan.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you could solve your issue, but as far as I know CNAMEs records aren’t allowed to co-exist with other records for the same name, that mean a NS, TXT, MX or SOA records, according to RFC 1912 [1].

If you are using CNAME, as a workaround, you can change the CNAME to A record, and then set up the TXT and MX records.

[1] https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1912.txt